# Cannot add ChangeDetectorRef as provider

Tags: angular

I am using ChangeDetectorRef to update a view after a web request.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { QRCodeModule } from 'angularx-qrcode';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-print',
  templateUrl: './print.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./print.component.css'],
})
export class PrintComponent implements OnInit {
  barcodeitems;
  selecteditems = [];

  constructor(public http: HttpClient, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  getqr() {
    console.log("selecteditems array", this.selecteditems);
    let filterQuery = this.selecteditems.map(i => `ID eq '${i}'`).join(" or ");
    let url = `https://example.com/corporate/dev/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Document Separator Barcodes')/items?$top=1000&$orderBy=ID&$filter=${filterQuery}`
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(data => {
      this.barcodeitems = data['value'];

      this.cdr.detectChanges();

    });
  }

}
```

Using `ng serve`, I am getting an error of : `Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[PrintComponent -> ChangeDetectorRef]: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[PrintComponent -> ChangeDetectorRef]: NullInjectorError: No provider for ChangeDetectorRef!`.

I have tried to add `ChangeDetectorRef` to `providers` in app.module.ts like this:

```
import { NgModule, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
.....

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PrintComponent } from './print/

print.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PrintComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    QRCodeModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [PrintComponent, ChangeDetectorRef],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This gives me an error of:

```
Argument of type '{ declarations: (typeof AppComponent | typeof PrintComponent)[]; imports: (typeof BrowserModule |...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NgModule'. Types of property 'providers' are incompatible. Type '(typeof PrintComponent | typeof ChangeDetectorRef)[]' is not assignable to type 'Provider[]'. Type 'typeof PrintComponent | typeof ChangeDetectorRef' is not assignable to type 'Provider'. Type 'typeof ChangeDetectorRef' is not assignable to type 'Provider'. Type 'typeof ChangeDetectorRef' is not assignable to type 'FactoryProvider'. Property 'provide' is missing in type 'typeof ChangeDetectorRef'.
```

How can I add `ChangeDetectorRef` as a provider?

Comment: You don't need to add ChangeDetectorRef to your providers, its already present by default. Just use it in the relevant component or service.

Comment: Why would I get the error: `No provider for ChangeDetectorRef!`?

Comment: It's a mystery to me as well, but removing it from the AppModule is step one. Are you sure you are on a angular version that has ChangeDetectorRef available?

Comment: Yes, Angular 5.2.

Comment: Seriously no idea why its not working for you guys. I'm not on the latest version of Angular though. Maybe something is broken at the moment. It used to be enough to import it directly in the component / service you wanted to use it in. Providing it to your module was never needed, and I can't find any info on this being needed now. You could try downgrading to angular 5.0, and see what happens then. Or create a new project and see if it also happens in a minimal repro.

Comment: Any luck with this issue ?

Comment: have you found any solution ?

Comment: In 6.1 I have a similar issue. The error in this case is: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MatCheckbox -> ChangeDetectorRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MatCheckbox -> ChangeDetectorRef]:

Comment: there's a github error report for this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14656 -- did anyone here solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you providing PrintComponent? You can't provide a component.... Remove the providers completely from your module, and it should work.